# Google chrome extension error

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

chrome-extension, stucked with the error

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'sendRequest' of undefined
```

here is my **code**

manifest.json

```
{
  "manifest_version": 2,
  "name": "blah",
  "version": "1.0",
  "description": "blah",
  "browser_action": {
    "default_icon": "icon.png"

    },
  "background": "bg.html", // change to your background page
  "permissions": ["http://*/*", "tabs"], //need permission to access all pages & tabs
   "content_scripts": [
   {
     "matches": ["http://*/*", "https://*/*"], // run for http & https pages
     "js": ["key_event.js"],  // key_event.js is injected to the page, this handles key press
     "run_at": "document_start" // run before everything else, else there will be conflicts at pages which accept keyboard inputs ( eg:google search)
   }
   ]
}
```

key_event.js

```
if (window == top) {
window.addEventListener('keyup', doKeyPress, false); //add the keyboard handler
}


function doKeyPress(e){
     if (e.keyCode == 17){ // if e.shiftKey is not provided then script will run at all instances of typing "G"
         alert("pressed");

        chrome.extension.sendRequest({redirect: "https://www.google.co.in"});//build newurl as per viewtext URL generated earlier.
     }
}
```

bg.html

```
chrome.extension.onRequest.addListener(function(request, sender) {
        chrome.tabs.update(sender.tab.id, {url: request.redirect});
    });
```

plz help me

Comment: is the error happening in `key_event.js` file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As already mentioned in comments

- The `background` section of manifest version 2 has to be like

  ```
  "background": {"scripts": ["bg.js"]}
  ```

There is no background page, only background scripts. So you'll have to move your code from bg.html to bg.js and remove all the extra HTML from it.

- `chrome.extension.sendRequest` and `chrome.extension.onRequest` have been deprecated in favor of `chrome.runtime.sendMessage` and `chrome.runtime.onMessage` respectively. That means, you can still use `sendRequest` and `onRequest` but it might be subject to removal in a future version of Chrome
- The keyCode for `G` is 71 rather than 17

Comment: done with .sendmessage and .onmessage, working great